# Probleme when trying to call another function of smart contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I have two smart contracts, one that is currently deployed and another one that is supposed to call a specific function of the first one. The first one contains a function with an uint256 and an address as arguments. The second one is supposed to call this function, passing as parameters a specific number and the address of the user calling the function.

Contract to call :

```
contract ToCall is Owner {
    
    function doSomething(uint256 number, address aRandomAddress) external onlyOwner {
        ///Do something...
    }
}
```

Contract calling :

```
contract Caller is Owner {

    function callOtherContract(uint256 number) external onlyOwner {
        (bool sucess,)=contractAddress.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("doSomething(uint256,address)", number, msg.sender);
        require(success);
    }
}
```

Every time I test, the "require(success)" doesn't pass, even though the 2nd contract is the owner of the first one. I think it might have something to do with the way I pass the parameters because I've already used this method to call other function of different smart contracts but never when using parameters. I could'nt find anything about the .call in the documentation so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Why dont you just call that method directly?

Comment: The `callOtherContract()` also contains the `onlyOwner` modifier. Can you check if the `msg.sender` is the `owner` in the `Caller` contract?